# How can i put images in listview from json object?

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I am able to convert jsonobject into list and display it in listview but i want images(Bitmap) to be displayed.When I try to do that I get image source link and id getting displayed instead of images.I am working on facebook graph api and want all the user posts (images) on my application.

Comment: Use picasso lib which is used as an ImageLoader lib.. you place the links with the code check out this document : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/

Comment: .load method of Picasso takes only one url at a time.How can i put 10-15 url one by one ?

Comment: When building the Items in Adapter place the link inside getView() Function .. the int position should return the link from your array/List

Comment: ok i l try thnks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting image link like this - http://theeducationaltourist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/shutterstock_148530896.jpg

then you use an image loading libraries that can load images in your imageview.
There are many libraries available :[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/), [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: .load method of Picasso takes only one url at a time.How can i put 10-15 url one by one ?

Comment: You have to write the Picasso method inside the getView method of your listview adapter where each item of your listview is inflated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @SatyajeetSen - Also please accept it as answer if it helped you

Comment: @Passionandroid Please see my other questions if you can answer (facebook graph api)

Comment: @SatyajeetSen - I cant find here. Send me a link to your questions.

Comment: @Passionandroid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956373/how-can-you-fetch-album-images-from-facebook-using-graph-api